# Vb.net form allow textbox value less than derived value in program

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

In vb.net module code, i have calculated some value, say 'Y' and then calling form which has textbox. I want to cross check user inputs and allow user to enter value which will be less than (calculated value 'Y' + 5) or greater than (calculated value 'Y' -5) only.
How to achive this ? Please advise. Many Thanks in advance

Below is part if code (pl note i have beginner level knowledge). I want to pass 'Y'  information to textbox1 and allow user to input value withinh +- 5 to Y value

Option strict off
Import System

Module Module1

Public AVal As Double = 0

Sub Main()

```
 Dim myExp() as Expression = workPart.Expression.ToArray

 Dim AExp As Expression = Nothing
 Dim Y As Double 

  For Each exp As Expression In myExp
    If exp.Name = "XYZ" Then
      AExp = exp
      Y = exp.Value
    End If
  Next

  Dim f1 As New Form1
  f1.Label1.Text = 
AExp.Name.tostring
  f1.TextBox1.Text = 
AExp.Value.tostring
  f1.showDialog()

 End Sub

 End Module

 Public class Form1
  '....

  ' TextBox1
  Me.TextBox1.location = Newew 
System.Drawing.point(102,40)
  Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
  Me.TextBox1.Size = Newew 
system.Drawing.size(154, 20)
  Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 1

  ......
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us your attempt please?

Comment: You're asking how to validate the contents of a `TextBox` so that's what you should be researching for yourself first. The specifics don't really matter too much because it sounds like basic algebra so you shouldn't need help with that. What you need to learn is how validation is performed in WinForms and that can be found with a web search. ALWAYS look first and ask questions later.

Comment: @jmcilhhinney, I searched on thse same... but new to this vb scripting.. not able to understand and realign my code.

Comment: @vts So I recommend creating a Console App, declaring some variables, comparing two variables with operators like `>`, `<` and learn something about bool algebra. If you have a basic understanding conditions you can easily transfer it to a WinForms project with TextBoxes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution using Keypress/lostfocus + fuction (to validate inputs with if). Thanks to everyone for comments.